# How to make each letter of a string a variable in python

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to make a encoder in python

Here is the code so far. It works fine but i want to change each letter in the string to the corresponding number eg: a=1, b=2. so then it would end up as a number sentence. My aim is to have 2 programs, one for encoding and one for decoding

```
print "Welcome to the encoder"
Letter1 = raw_input ("Please input the first letter of the word: ")
Letter2 = raw_input ("Please input the second letter of the word: ")
Letter3 = raw_input ("Please input the third letter of the word: ")
Letter4 = raw_input ("Please input the fourth letter of the word: ")
Letter5 = raw_input ("Please input the fifth letter of the word: ")
Letter6 = raw_input ("Please input the sixth letter of the word: ")
Letter7 = raw_input ("Please input the seventh letter of the word: ")
Letter8 = raw_input ("Please input the eighth letter of the word: ")
Letter9 = raw_input ("Please input the ninth letter of the word: ")
Letter10 = raw_input ("Please input the tenth letter of the word: ")
Letter11 = raw_input ("Please input the eleventh letter of the word: ")
Letter12 = raw_input ("Please input the twelvth letter of the word: ")
print "Your code is " + Letter3 + Letter2 + Letter1 + Letter6 + Letter5 
+ Letter4 + Letter9 + Letter8 + Letter7 + Letter12 + Letter11 + 
Letter10
```

Comment: Below you can find my solution @BogdanRasputin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `dict` (dictionary) to store each letter and its corresponding number. This is flexible if you would like to change the code to something other than than the ordinal of the letter.

```
# define the dictionary
encoder = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5"}

# take your input
Letter1 = raw_input ("Please input the first letter of the word: ")
Letter2 = raw_input ("Please input the first letter of the word: ")
Letter3 = raw_input ("Please input the first letter of the word: ")

# print out the encoded version
print encoder[Letter1] + encoder[Letter2] + encoder[Letter3]
```

Comment: Great, that's a fun project you have there. I encourage you to keep playing around with it, encoding and decoding is excellent programming practice!

Comment: @Matt I completely agree

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using variables to store each letter, it would be more concise and easier to scale if you use a list and append each `raw_input` to the list.

```
print "Welcome to the encoder"
code_length = 12
code = []
for index in xrange(0, code_length):
    letter = raw_input  ("Please input letter " + str(index) + " of the word: ")
    ordinal = ord(letter) - 96
    code.append(str(ordinal))

print ' '.join(code)
```

Comment: Invalid syntax?

Comment: I apologize for the missing `)`. Fixed.

Comment: Please note that if the user enters a NULL value or a more than one letter it will fail. I could add the additional answer validation, but this seems more like a prototype to get you started on an idea rather than production code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ord() method in python and do it.

```
word = raw_input()

print('Your code is\n')
for letter in word:
    print ord(letter)-96
```

Comment: looks like this question is in python2 so no print function. Using `print ord(letter)-96,` would print it out on one line like what the code provided in the question is trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
Letter1,Letter2,Letter3,Letter4,Letter5,Letter6,Letter7,Letter8,Letter9,Letter10,Letter11,Letter12=[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],['']
def encoder():
  print "Welcome to the encoder"
  [Letter1.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the first letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter2.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the second letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter3.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the third letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter4.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the fourth letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter5.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the fifth letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter6.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the sixth letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter7.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the seventh letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter8.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the eighth letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter9.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the ninth letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter10.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the tenth letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter11.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the eleventh letter of the word: ")]
  [Letter12.append(str(ord(c)-96)) for c in raw_input ("Please input the twelvth letter of the word: ")]
  print "Your code is " + ''.join(Letter3) + ''.join(Letter2) + ''.join(Letter1) + ''.join(Letter6) + ''.join(Letter5) + ''.join(Letter4) + ''.join(Letter9) + ''.join(Letter8) + ''.join(Letter7) + ''.join(Letter12) + ''.join(Letter11) + ''.join(Letter10)

def decoder():
  Letter112 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter1[1:]]
  Letter21 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter2[1:]]
  Letter31 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter3[1:]]
  Letter41 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter4[1:]]
  Letter51 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter5[1:]]
  Letter61 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter6[1:]]
  Letter71 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter7[1:]]
  Letter81 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter8[1:]]
  Letter91 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter9[1:]]
  Letter101 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter10[1:]]
  Letter111 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter11[1:]]
  Letter121 = [chr(int(c)+96) for c in Letter12[1:]]
  print "Your code is " + ''.join(Letter31) + ''.join(Letter21) + ''.join(Letter112) + ''.join(Letter61) + ''.join(Letter51) + ''.join(Letter41) + ''.join(Letter91) + ''.join(Letter81) + ''.join(Letter71) + ''.join(Letter121) + ''.join(Letter111) + ''.join(Letter101)

encoder()
decoder()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the encoder
Please input the first letter of the word:  asdf
Please input the second letter of the word:  b
Please input the third letter of the word:  g
Please input the fourth letter of the word:  r
Please input the fifth letter of the word:  d
Please input the sixth letter of the word:  w
Please input the seventh letter of the word:  r
Please input the eighth letter of the word:  c
Please input the ninth letter of the word:  g
Please input the tenth letter of the word:  d
Please input the eleventh letter of the word:  s
Please input the twelvth letter of the word:  c
Your code is 72119462341873183194
Your code is gbasdfwdrgcrcsd
```

Comment: so if you think it's better ans you can accept my answer welcome